# What is the difference between Filesystem(device location) and Mounted point? both seems to be directory

Tags: linux

What is the difference between Filesystem(device location) and Mounted point?
Both seems to be directory.

Where does actual data/files of the mounted device reside? in filesystem or mount point?

What is the use of mount point if actual data lives in Filesystem?

```
#df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952    970228   7202856  12% /
tmpfs                   308520         0    308520   0% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A (physical) file system is a disk or partition, formatted in a certain way, and containing data structures comprising directories and files.

Every physical file system has a root directory indicated as `/` in Linux.

Now this structure maps to a logical view. A simple logical view maps one physical file system one-on-one to your logical file system. This is called 'mounting a file system'.

You can mount a physical file system (or part of it) to a different logical node, called a 'mount point'. This means, your physical file system root `/` can be mounted to your logical "directory" `/my/logical/mount`.
If your physical file system contains a file `rootfile` in its physical root directory, you may access exactly that file by its logical name `/my/logical/mount/rootfile`.

The physical location is still on the physical file system, your access through the "mount point" is just a logical link to access that data.

Mount are useful for organizing various file systems, for combining several disks/partitions into one logical structure, and to combine various disparate devices and views into the same structure, from disks, partitions, USB sticks, floppy drives, remote network drives and even terminals, all logically residing under your logical root `/`.

Comment: thanks. can i mount different physical devices to the same mount point?

Comment: Not the same, but in parallel. A mount point identifies the (file system) driver and the exact drive/partition/location, of which there can only be one per mount point. But something like `/dev/hd0` and `/dev/hd1` can be two drives in your system. You can mount one drive/partition in two different locations, possibly one as read-only, one as writable, though.

Comment: i got it, one last question. suppose /dev/xvda1 is mounted on mount point '/', you can see in question. As i understand any file under physical media /dev/xvda1 can be accessed by /A correct? At the same time can i access it like /dev/xvda1/A

Comment: Theoretically, yes. However, `/` is a special case, since it is the root of your logical world and doesn't have a name. A mount point has a name like 'm1' or 'dev', and the logical root ties all "first level" mount points together. If you want to go into details, you may need someone else to answer your questions, my experience in this is quite dated, even if the basics still apply.

Comment: but xvda1 is listed as brw-rw---- 1 root disk    202,   1 Dec  1 14:49 xvda1, in dev directory and i can't see it as its not a directory. so i guess /A is only option

Comment: And, of course, you need one boot volume, off which the logical root is mounted. There the logical `/` maps to its physical `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem refers to the actual device holding the data.  Mount is a logical concept of mapping of a filesystem device to a path.

Comment: What is the use of mount point if actual data lives in Filesystem?

Comment: It's an abstraction.  For example, each user on a linux machine could choose to mount the same physical disk to a different path.

Answer (score 0):

You mount a file system on a mount point.

A file system basically tells you how stuff is laid out on the underlying (physical) medium, while the mount point gives the path to where the information from the file system will be accessible later.